# How to check outstanding fines in the US as a tourist

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal

A year ago I rented a car in Miami, and I might have gone though a red light, in front of a red light camera.

After checking, I saw that the car rental company entered the wrong address of my home country.

In a few months I’m going to NY, and I want to be sure I didn’t get a fine. Is there a way to check if there are any open warrants for non-US residents?

If not, what is likely to happen at the immigrations?

Comment: Your fine - if received - would be delivered to the rental company. They would either charge your credit card with the fine amount (they have this option in the rental agreement you've signed), or send it back stating its a rental car, and sending your name/address (in this case they may charge you a fixed "admin fee" for that - this is not the fine). There it most likely would get dismissed, once they see you are not in the US - collecting this fine would be expensive and troublesome and generally not likely to be worth it. If curious, you can email the rental company and ask.

Comment: @GeorgeY. you could make that an answer.